Can't route to a public page in my Blazor Server app
I have developed a blazor server side application that works perfectly, however now I want to add a public page and I can't get the public page to display. When I direct the browser to https://localhost:44385/NewRegistration it appears to redirect, but the page is blank. If I enter a non existent page it will redirect to the login for authentication as it should. Here's my programs.cs file:
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseHsts();

app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/NewRegistration", async context =>
    {
        app.MapControllers();
        app.MapBlazorHub();

        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/NewRegistration").AllowAnonymous();

    }).AllowAnonymous();
});
app.Run();


The app.razor page is:
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectLogin />
            </NotAuthorized>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

And the public page is:
@page "/NewRegistration"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<h1>New Registration</h1>

@code{
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}

Any help is appreciated.

Your public page NewRegistration is still a blazor component.  In .Net7 the componets are routing by app.MapFallbackToPage("/xxx"). The path has to be a RazorPage (such as _Host.cshmtl, but /NewRegistration is meaningless blazor component)
MapGet is a minimal api endpoint which conflict with component routing. I could see you may want conditional middleware pipeline here but with a wrong pattern. And I don't think it is neccessary to use MapGet to route to the NewRegistration component.
So you should delete the entire app.UseEndpoints(...) to make "https://localhost:44385/NewRegistration" work normally.

Qiang Fu,   Thanks for the quick response.   I'm not sure I understand.   I created a new public page as a RazorPage call Register.   I removed the app.UseEndPoints(...) and simply added app.MapFallbackToPage("/Register") and I get the error on launch regarding endpoints using the same priority.   If I put back the app.UseEndPoints block of code modified to point "/Register" I'm back to a blank page.
